# GoogleSQL - SELECT IF

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm working with a dataset - structured like this

[image]

I want to exclude all records with ReviewRound being "a" **if they have gone through review round "b"** - If a set of unique ID's has an associated round "b" review, the round "a" review should not be included.

Some records have not gone to round "b". The issues I'm running into are as a result of there being multiple records for each unique ID.

Ideally this could be done in GoogleBigQuery, if not, filtering through GoogleScripts may also be an option!

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> If a set of unique ID's has an associated round "b" review, the round "a" review should not be included.

If I followed you correctly, you could express this as a `not` condition with a correlated subquery that ensures that, if the current record has `ReviewRound = 'a'`, there is no other record that has the same `id` and `ReviewRound = 'b'`.

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not (
    t.ReviewRound = 'a'
    and exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        and t1.id = t.id and t1.ReviewRound = 'b'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions as well:

```
select t.* except (num_bs)
from (select t.*,
             countif(reviewround = 'b') over (partition by id) as num_bs
      from t
     ) t
where num_bs = 0 or reviewround = 'b';
```

Answer (score 0):

By using window functions, you can solve it with this query

```
SELECT ID, Score
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ReviewRound = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (partition by ID) as has_b
  FROM mytable
) t
WHERE has_b = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-conceptualizing as keeping only the latest review round, I would try:

```
select * from mytable join
(select ID, max(ReviewRound) as ReviewRound from mytable group by ID)
on (ID, ReviewRound)
```